# How to make a receptacle box flush with wall after it has been installed?

Tags: electrical

[image: blue box]
We have two receptacle blue boxes installed. Both were going to be in back splash wall so contractors had them not flush with the wall, I guess accounting for the thickness of the tiles.

Long story short. We're not gong to have a back splash around one of the blue boxes.

How do I make this blue box flush with the wall?  Also you can see that the blue box is not evenly inset. Left side and top sticks out more than the right side and bottom.

Do I just trim the plastic down so that it is flush? Does that somehow make it not up to code?

Comment: I can't support the following statement at this time. But I would suggest as it  is only one box that you could simply cut the box out and replace it with an old work box.

Comment: What is that rectangular piece of blue plastic on the left inside?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The box looks like this type of [adjustable depth box](http://www.truevalue.com//catalog/product.jsp?productId=21555&parentCategoryId=4&categoryId=54&subCategoryId=474&type=product&cid=gooshop&source=google_pla&9gtype=%7Bifsearch:search%7D%7Bifcontent:content%7D&9gkw=%7Bkeyword%7D&9gad=%7Bcreative%7D.1&9gpla=%7Bplacement%7D&ctcampaign=4680&ctkwd=%7Bproduct_id%7D&ctmatch=&ctcreative=%7BCreative%7D&ctplacement=806521-44622122499&gclid=CjwKEAiAu6DBBRDDr6-e_6698E0SJACvuxnyxvFLQk4rWXJKlm9rDneCW64nNuEjKEo7IQrl1JIhJBoCN97w_wcB). Try tightening the screw but if the box doesn't move you should cut away adhering drywall mud or calk, until it does move. Given the metal bracket which supports the box it is surprising that it is not square to the wall. Maybe it will straighten as it is pulled into the wall, but if it doesn't it will be OK to use. Get some of those plastic shims for receptacles and put the right number on the screw of the receptacle to put it in the plane of the wall.

Answer (score 10):

That is an adjustable box.

Along the right vertical side you see that screw? That screw will adjust the box in and out. But since someone painted/caulked it in you will need to free it up all around the drywall edge.

I have to say though, whoever installed it in the first place did a really shitty job. It should sit even all the way around.

Comment: Isn't the blue box nailed to the stud? Is there a sliding track for the blue box?

Comment: http://www.homedepot.com/p/1-Gang-21-cu-in-Non-Metallic-Wall-Box-with-Adjustable-Bracket-B121ADJ-40R/202077339 ... (pictures being a thousand words and all)

Comment: We have plaster walls so could that have contributed to the uneven depth? The walls are to blame? :)

Comment: @milesmeow, it's possible.

Comment: I don't think the wall is the problem. The studs or the surface of the wall would have to be out of plumb by an impossible amount. Fiddle with the electrical box and see what happens.